# Calling javascript function in iframe

Tags: javascript, function, iframe

I have problem calling a JavaScript function in an `iframe` from the parent page. Here is my two pages:

**mainPage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MainPage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Reset() 
        {
            if (document.all.resultFrame)
                alert("resultFrame found");
            else
                alert("resultFrame NOT found");

            if (typeof (document.all.resultFrame.Reset) == "function")
                document.all.resultFrame.Reset();
            else
                alert("resultFrame.Reset NOT found");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    MainPage<br>
    <input type="button" onclick="Reset()" value="Reset"><br><br>
    <iframe height="100" id="resultFrame" src="resultFrame.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

**resultFrame.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>ResultPage</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Reset() 
        {
            alert("reset (in resultframe)");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ResultPage
</body>
</html>
```

(I know that `document.all` isn't recommended but this page should only be viewed with IE internally and I don't think that's the problem)

When I press the Reset-button I get "resultFrame found" and "resultFrame.Reset NOT found". It seems to have a reference to the frame but can't call the function on the frame, why is that?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking JavaScript code in an iframe from the parent page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Use:

```
document.getElementById("resultFrame").contentWindow.Reset();
```

to access the Reset function in the iframe

`document.getElementById("resultFrame")`
will get the iframe in your code, and `contentWindow` will get the window object in the iframe. Once you have the child window, you can refer to javascript in that context.

Also see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-in-iframe-from-parent-page)  in particular the answer from bobince.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, does the .contentWindow still work? I do `console.log(document.getElementById('iframeID').contentWindow)` and in Firebug it correctly shows my `test()` function in my iframe, but when I go to call the function it says it's not a function, but it is! Testing it in FF4.

Answer (score 7):

For even more robustness:

```
function getIframeWindow(iframe_object) {
  var doc;

  if (iframe_object.contentWindow) {
    return iframe_object.contentWindow;
  }

  if (iframe_object.window) {
    return iframe_object.window;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.contentDocument) {
    doc = iframe_object.contentDocument;
  } 

  if (!doc && iframe_object.document) {
    doc = iframe_object.document;
  }

  if (doc && doc.defaultView) {
   return doc.defaultView;
  }

  if (doc && doc.parentWindow) {
    return doc.parentWindow;
  }

  return undefined;
}
```

and

```
...
var el = document.getElementById('targetFrame');

var frame_win = getIframeWindow(el);

if (frame_win) {
  frame_win.reset();
  ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of getting the frame from the document, try getting the frame from the window object.

in the above example change this:

```
if (typeof (document.all.resultFrame.Reset) == "function")
    document.all.resultFrame.Reset();
else
    alert("resultFrame.Reset NOT found");
```

to

```
if (typeof (window.frames[0].Reset) == "function")
    window.frames[0].Reset();
else
    alert("resultFrame.Reset NOT found");
```

the problem is that the scope of the javascript inside the iframe is not exposed through the DOM element for the iframe.  only window objects contain the javascript scoping information for the frames.

Answer (score 4):

Call

```
window.frames['resultFrame'].Reset();
```

Answer (score 3):

`objectframe.contentWindow.Reset()` you need reference to the top level element in the frame first.

Answer (score 2):

The first and foremost condition that needs to be met is that both the parent and iframe should belong to the same origin. Once that is done the child can invoke the parent using window.opener method and the parent can do the same for the child as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

If you can not use it directly and if you encounter this error:
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www..com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
You can use [postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) instead of using the function directly.

Answer (score 0):

When you access resultFrame through document.all it only pulls it as an HTML element, not a window frame. You get the same issue if you have a frame fire an event using a "this" self-reference.

Replace:

```
document.all.resultFrame.Reset();
```

With:

```
window.frames.resultFrame.Reset();
```

Or:

```
document.all.resultFrame.contentWindow.Reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

### Calling a privacy-respecting `XMLHttpRequest` from an `<iframe>`

HTML:

```html
<iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

JavaScript:

```js
const iframe    = document.getElementById('iframe');
const iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframeWin.document;

let script = iframeDoc.createElement('SCRIPT');

script.append(`function sendWithoutOrigin(url) {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', url);

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if(request.status === 200) {
                console.log('GET succeeded.');
            }
            else {
                console.warn('GET failed.');
            }
        }
    }
    request.send();
}`);

iframeDoc.documentElement.appendChild(script);
```

JavaScript evocation:

```js
let url  = 'https://api.serivce.net/';
    url += '?api_key=' + api_write_key;
    url += '&field1=' + value;

iframeWin.sendWithoutOrigin(url);
```