# Javascript disabled inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iFrame which points to facebookAuthentification. It makes a redirect via JavaScript.

Actually nothing happens and it looks like JavaScript is not executed. 
Sandbox mode is not set and it doesn't work either when sandbox mode is set to execute scripts.

The JavaScript redirect works outside the iframe very nice

There is the JS code which is inside the iframe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">self.location.href="redirect.php"</script>
```

Comment: Great, so JavaScript doesn't work in the iframe. What's your question?

Comment: perhaps this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe