# open local page in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two iframes and I need to load another local page (help_content.html) (into my bottomframe) on the click of a button (in my topframe). The topframe has a form (help_form.html) with 3 buttons (2 which work) and the bottomframe is currently a blank.html that needs to load help_screen.html on the click of the button.

**HTML from help_screen.html**

```
<iframe name="topframe" id="topframe" src="help_form.html"><p>Your browser cannot view iFrames</p></iframe>
<br/>
<iframe name="bottomframe" id="bottomframe" src="blank.html"><p>Your browser cannot view iFrames</p></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
function openHelp() {       
document.getElementById("bottomframe").src="help_screen.html";
    }
```

**HTML from button on help_form.html**

```
<input type="button" name="help1" value="Click for help" onclick="openHelp()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript,
you have set the `src` to `help_screen.html`
while you should have set it to `help_content.html`

**EDIT**

help_screen.html must contain this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openHelp() {

                 var frame = document.getElementById("bottomframe");
                 frame.setAttribute("src", "help_content.html");
            }
        </script>
    </head>


    <body>
        <iframe name="topframe" id="topframe" src="help_form.html">Your browser suckss...</iframe>

        <iframe name="bottomframe" id="bottomframe" src="#">Your browser really suckss...</iframe>
     </body>             
</html>
```

Your help_form.html must contain this button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="parent.window.openHelp()">
```

Comment: Thank you Aditya for your response. 
I have just tried all combinations, but unfortunately it still is not working.

Comment: Thanks, but it still is not working. 

My directory is follows...

order_form.html (main page with a button that opens help_screen.html)
help_screen.html (has both the iframes - topframe and bottomframe)
help_form.html (populates the iframe (topframe) and has the button to onclick to populate the bottomframe with help_content.html) 
help_content.html (is the page I want to populate the bottomframe)
blank_page.html (is the current page of bottomframe)

I think you may be on the right track, but maybe missing one step in the mass of pages.

Comment: The aim is to open a window that when the button is clicked on the top frame, it opens the help below to give instructions on filling out the form above it.

Comment: @aingelic Can you please tell me in which file did you place your javascript snippet? and does your `help_screen.html` opens up on a separate tab, on the same tab, or in an iframe?

Comment: I have a javascript file called music.js that is linked to my html pages

Comment: what have you linked `music.js` in your `help_screen.html` file?

Comment: <script rel="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/music.js"></script> as with all my pages on my site

Comment: My help_screen.html open from my order_form.html 
<input type="button" name="help" value="Help" onclick= "helpWin()"/>
function helpWin() {
 window.open("help_screen.html","_blank","width=424, height=434");
}

Comment: write the openHelp() function separately in help_screen.html and then use parent.window.openHelp()

Comment: I would love to do that as a work around, but I have to have all of the javascript in my js file as it is an assignment and thats what the directions state.

Comment: I just asking you to try that once. if it works, put it back in your .is file. coz if it works by separating out the openHelp function, means that there is some problem in linking your. is file

Comment: I tried and it does not work either. I can get an alert to pop up, but content wont load.

Comment: Ok, do it like this... `document.getElementById("bottomFrame").setAttribute("src", "help_screen.html")`

Comment: Thank you @Aditya, but that also is not working unfortunately

Comment: Thanks Aditya. I feel silly for that mistake. With those changes in your current edit, I still can not get it to run.

Comment: you should keep all your files in the same directory. and test it out

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call the `window` field of the parent, just call the function directly from it, since `parent` is already a reference to the `window`:

```
onclick="parent.openHelp();"
```

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161388/iframe-function-calling-from-iframe-to-parent-page-javascript-function) suggests (quoting):

> … See [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.parent)
>
> Returns a reference to the parent of the current window or subframe.
>
> If a window does not have a parent, its parent property is a reference
>   to itself.
>
> When a window is loaded in an <iframe>, <object>, or <frame>, its
>   parent is the window with the element embedding the window.

Provided that the function is defined on `help_screen.html`.

However, if your function is defined on a child, you should call it like this ([as this question suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe)):

```
parent.document.getElementById("bottomFrame").contentWindow.openHelp();
```

Or:

```
parent.document.bottomFrame.contentWindow.openHelp();
```

Comment: Thank you arielnmz. I have just attempted all your suggestions, but still having no luck to get it to show.

Comment: Where is the javascript code defined? If you put an `alert('hola');` right at the beginning of your function, do you actually see the alert?

Comment: Yes the alert will pop up onclick of the button

Comment: What is the output of `alert(document.getElementById("bottomFrame"));`?

Comment: it says null when it pops up

Comment: Your javascript function is in `help_screen.html` right?

Comment: No, I have a javascript file called music.js that is linked to my html pages. '<script rel="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/music.js"></script>'. The onlick event happens from 'help_form.html' which is in the topframe,

Comment: Then you have to get the reference to the frame where `help_screen.html` is loaded and then get the reference of the frame you want to change, like this:  `document.getElementById("yourTopFrame").contentWindow.getElementById("bottomFrame").src = …`

Comment: Am I using that just with `onclick="openHelp();"` ?

Comment: So, `help_form.html` contains a frame that loads `help_screen.html` right? and the button is in `help_form.html` right? and the javascript function is defined on or linked to `help_form.html` right? Please put your frames hierarchy and where is the javascript loaded and from where the function is executed.

Comment: Aditya who is also responding just noticed in my original post that in my original javascript, I was asking for the src as `help_screen.html` instead of `help_content.html`! Silly me!

Comment: My directory is follows... `order_form.html` (main page with a button that opens `help_screen.html`) `help_screen.html` (has both the iframes - topframe and bottomframe) `help_form.html` (populates the iframe (topframe) and has the button to onclick to populate the bottomframe with `help_content.html`) `help_content.html` (is the page I want to populate the bottomframe) `blank_page.html` (is the current page of bottomframe)

Comment: My help_screen.html opens from my order_form.html `<input type="button" name="help" value="Help" onclick= "helpWin()"/>`  `function helpWin() { window.open("help_screen.html","_blank","width=424, height=434"); }`

Comment: Where is the function defined?

Comment: My functions are all in my music.js file

Comment: Where is it being linked?

Comment: There is a `<script rel="Javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../javascript/music.js"></script>` in the head of all my pages

Comment: Ok, now what is the page that calls the function?

Comment: the 'help_form.html' has the onclick event

Comment: just make that function get a reference of the document that holds the frame that you want to change, i.e. `openHelp(document)`, then you just find your frame on that document and modify the src.

Comment: Im not sure I follow correctly. So the `openHelp(document)` goes in the onclick event or I do that in the function itself?

Comment: Both, also please post your complete frames hierarchy.

Comment: in the function, do I do `document.getElementById("bottomfra‌​me").src = "help_content.html";`??? Sorry just feeling a little confused again now after everything else I have been trying. Still a newbie.

Comment: Yes, only if such id, `bottomFrame` is directly accessible from where you call the function, please put your frames hierarchy on your question.

Comment: `<body>
 <iframe name="topframe" id="topframe" src="help_form.html"><p>Your browser cannot view iFrames</p></iframe>
    <br/>
 <iframe name="bottomframe" id="bottomframe" src="blank.html"><p>Your browser cannot view iFrames</p></iframe>
</body>`

Comment: order_form.html - button onclick opens function helpWin()
helpWin() function opens a window, which is populated by help_screen.html
help_screen.html has two iframes ("topframe" and "bottomframe")
topframe is populated by help_form.html
bottomframe is populated by blank.html
help_form.html has button onclick openHelp()
openHelp() should populate bottomframe with help_content.html

Comment: Ok so you have to call `parent.document.bottomFrame.src = …` on your function

Comment: I thank you so very much for your time and effort, but this still doesn't seem to be working. I did `function openHelp(document) {  
 parent.document.bottomframe.src="help_content.html";
}` and then `onclick="openHelp(document);"`

Comment: I think you might have to move your button and your JavaScript yo the page that contains the frame that you want to change

Comment: Thanks @arielnmz I really appreciate all your help. Unfortunately I have to keep it as is, as that is how Ive have been requested to do it for my assignment. I will just keep playing with it and use all the information you've been able to provide me with and hope that it eventually fall into place. :)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by using `function openHelp(document){ parent.document.getElementById('bottomframe').src="help_content.html";
}`
Although it wont work on Chrome, I am happy it is working at all.
Thank you very much @Aditya and @arielnmz for all your help. It is appreciated.