# Run javascript function which is inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a javascript function, which is located inside the iframe.

```
<script>
document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.setupCookie()
</script>

<iframe id="myFrame" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<script>
function setupCookie() {
    document.cookie = "guvenli=1";
}
</script>

<center style="margin-top:200px;">
            <a href="javascript:;" 
    onClick="setupCookie(); location.href='/index.php'">Enter Site >></a></center>
```

What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Does what you have work?  You might need to wait until the iframe is *loaded* before you can call `setupCookie()`.

Comment: This is a correct way. + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe The problem might be because you are trying to access it when iframe does not exist (it is below the line addressing it) or content not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is correct, but your iframe needs to load before you can reference it with Javascript.

You should wait for the DOM content to load

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.setupCookie();
});
```

Comment: Why this listener is attached to `document` of the current window and not to the `iframe`?

Comment: Because the iframe is part of the document and doesn't exist until the document has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments above:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.setupCookie();
});
```