# Accessing function of iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a window in which I am loading an iframe.

The location of the window is

```
"http://localhost/current/test.html"
```

and the location of the iframe is

```
"http://localhost/current/testFrame.html"
```

And a script in my test.html is trying to access a function which is present in the scope of iframe window. 
But it is giving Permission Denied.

For eg From my main window I am executing this line of script

```
$("iframe")[0].contentWindow.getState();   //Permission Denied
```

And i am trying to access that function when the iframe is completely loaded.

How can the parent window access the function of iframe as both  windows are in the same origin.

Comment: Which browser? Or all browsers?

Comment: So strange you getting CORS problem with same domain pages. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/364997/1267304) out.

Comment: You have to make a research before asking.
[old question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque That does not explain the permission denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use javascript **postMessage** and create a cross window API system

for example:

**parent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>parent</title>
    <script>
        function iframeAction(actionId){
            var iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');
            iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(actionId,'*');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="iframeAction(1)">do iframe action 1</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="iframeAction(2)">do iframe action 2</button>
    <br>
    <iframe src="./iframe.html" id="myIframe" />
</body>

</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>parent</title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        //page generic functions
        function doActoin_1(){$("#labal").html("Action 1");}
        function doActoin_2(){$("#labal").html("Action 2");}

        // Listen to message from parent
        var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        var eventer = window[eventMethod];
        var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

        eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
            switch(e.data){
                case 1: doActoin_1(); break;
                case 2: doActoin_2(); break;
            }           
        },false);

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="labal">iFrame</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see that the iframe.html contains normal javascript function, But by adding a window listener you are able to create a dynamic API for ader windows to use.

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving what you want would be using `window.postMessage` to kick of the inner function and use another message to return the result to the parent.

In iframe:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
   var state = getState();
   e.source.postMessage(state, "*");
}, false);
```

In the parent:

```
window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  var state = e.data; //do something with your data
}, false);

$("iframe")[0].contentWindow.postMessage("getState", "*");
```

Just replace the * with your domain. More details can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

Answer (score -2):

You can access an iframe using `window.frames` property.

`window.frames[0]` should give first iframe.

Example -

```
 <iframe name="frame1" src="testframe.html"></iframe>
```

can be accessed with

```
window.frames["frame1"]
```

should give the `window` object for the `iframe`.

Comment: UM, how is that any different than `$("iframe")[0]`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question.

Comment: Not sure about the jQuery part, does it return the window object?