# how to call a child element from parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

consider the below given two HTML pages

parent.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id='parent' onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<div  class='test-ab' id="load"></div>
</body>

<script>
  function test()
  {
    //need to call child function or button
  }

  $(function(){
    $('#load').html('<object id="webloader" data="child.html"/>');
  });
</script>
</html>
```

child.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button id='child' onclick="helloworld()">Click Me</button>
</body>
<script>
  function helloworld()
  {
    alert("hello world");
  }
</script>

</html>
```

there are two defined HTML pages defined, is there any way to call the child.html function (eg here:-helloworld()) from parent.html

Comment: Assuming both pages are on the same domain then you could use an `iframe`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe. A better method entirely would be to create your own library of common functions and include it in both pages.

Comment: current I have loaded it through the object tag, currently the function is defined under child.html only

Comment: why don't use put all javascript in one file and load it in both html pages ?

Comment: @paradox yep, and it won't work that way

Comment: i could access parent functions through parent.function() in child.html, in the same way i thought we could for parent to child access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [postMessage mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)

Regards,
Vincent

Comment: will it work for the HTML page defined with <object> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let child_element = $("#parent").find(".load");
```

Comment: can you give me an example how to use it please

Comment: Yes, I can. please describe the condition.

Comment: when I click the parent button "Click Me" I need to call child HTML function helloworld() as given in example code

Comment: I suggest you check your HTML code first, as I found lots of HTML errors in your code.
1) <button onclick="helloworld() id='child'">Click Me</button>
2) <button onclick="test() id='parent'">Click Me</button>

wrong format to call a function