# How do I execute a line of javascript in another iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

There is an url `www.example.com/page-1.php`. This page has a function called `make_circle`. Used like this: `make_circle('10');`

When I visit `www.example.com/page-2.php`, I want it to run `make_circle('10');` on  `www.example.com/page-1.php`. Is this possible?

---

On `www.example.com/page-2.php`:

```
<iframe id="coolpage" src="www.example.com/page-1.php" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>
<!-- How do I run the make_circle function on page-1 while I am on page-2 -->
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe

Comment: I literally copied your questions title and got the result for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page in google.

Comment: @epascarello `document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.targetFunction();` What is the `targetFrame` id? is it the id in the iframe? In my case its called `coolpage`

Comment: @Kiwa: Yes. But how you get a reference to the iframe element doesn't matter. This is just an example.