# Call a function from another HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

for Example I have a html page :

```
a.html
```

and I have another html page :

```
b.html
```

and a button in `a.html`

```
<button id="btnsayhello" onClick="SayHello()">Say Hello</button>
```

and a function in `a.html` script tag :

```
function SayHello() {
alert("Hello");
```

}

and a function in `b.html` script tag :

```
function down(sec) {
    setTimeout("location.href='" + "a.html" + "'", sec * 1000);
    $("#btnsayhello").click();
```

}

this code is not correct , but how Can I do this ?
I want to click a button of a html page from another html page.

Comment: you should rather use one script file on both pages and pass parameters across the pages, maybe that was what you intended initially.. since in HTML, more than one or more pages can utilize the same external js or css file.

Comment: If one of the pages is in an iframe, you can [call a function in the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe) from the other page.

Answer (score 1):

Put your javascript in an external file (like `scripts.js`) and include it in each of your html files:

```html
<script src="path/to/scripts.js"></script>
```