# Cannot access javascript function in ADF InlineFrame

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I have a jsff page containing `af:InlineFrame`.

The source of this InlineFrame is HTML file say `Frame.html`

This html file has a javascript function called `inlineframeFunction()`

I have a button added in the `jsff` page.

My usecase is to invoke the function inlineframeFunction on click of the button which i am not able achieve.

```
var doc = inlineFrame.contentDocument? 
inlineFrame.contentDocument: inlineFrame.contentWindow.document;
doc.frameFunction();
```

### Frame.html

```
<script type="javascript">    
    function inlineframeFunction(){
        alert('Inline Frame Function ');
    }
  </script>
```

### JSFF Page

```
<af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl1" layout="vertical">

      <af:resource type="javascript">

        function inlineFrameRegionPageFunction() {
          alert('Region Page Function');
          var inlineFrame = document.getElementById('r1:0:if2');
          var doc = inlineFrame.contentDocument? inlineFrame.contentDocument: inlineFrame.contentWindow.document;
          doc.frameFunction();
        }
      </af:resource>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
    <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2" layout="vertical">
      <af:panelBox text="Inline Frame Region" id="pb2"
                   inlineStyle="background-color:Lime; border-color:Lime;">
        <f:facet name="toolbar"/>
        <af:inlineFrame id="if2" source="/Frame.html" shortDesc="InlineFrame"
                        inlineStyle="background-color:Gray;"/>
        <af:commandButton text="Inline Region Button" id="rb2"
                          actionListener="#{pageFlowScope.RegionBean.onClickInlineFrameRgnButton}"/>
      </af:panelBox>
    </af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Comment: Is the question about the actionListener Java to call your js "inlineframeFunction" ?

Comment: Yes you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute a javascript from a managed bean in adf you can use the following function (https://cedricleruth.com/how-to-execute-client-javascript-in-an-adf-java-bean-action/) :

```
/*** In YOURJSF.jsf button, or other component that need to execute a javascript on action, add : ****/
<af:commandButton text="ClickMe" id="cb1" actionListener="#{YOURSCOPE.YOURJAVABEAN.clickToExecuteJavascriptAction}"/>

 /*** In YOURJAVABEAN.java class add : ***/
 public void clickToExecuteJavascriptAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
  this.executeClientJavascript("console.log('You just clicked : " + actionEvent.getSource() + " ')");
  //Note: if you use a java string value in this function you should escape it to avoid breaking the javascript.
  //Like this : stringValue.replaceAll("[^\\p{L}\\p{Z}]", " ")
 }

//You should put this function in a util java class if you want to use it in multiple bean
public static void executeClientJavascript(String script) {
 FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 ExtendedRenderKitService service = Service.getRenderKitService(facesContext, ExtendedRenderKitService.class);
 service.addScript(facesContext, script);
}
```

Then in your case, refer to this question to call your iframe js function using javascript inside your action listener ([Calling javascript function in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe))

```
document.getElementById("if2").contentWindow.inlineframeFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following and it worked!

```
    function inlineFrameRegionPageFunction() {          
       var frameComp =$('[id*="InlineFrame"]', document)[0].id;
    document.getElementById(frameComp).contentWindow.frameFunction();
    }
  </af:resource>
```