# JavaScript: Call iFrame Function from Developer Console

Tags: javascript, html

I need to call a function which is in iFrame from developer console. But I'm unable to do that.

I tried the following and I get a error that its not a function.

`document.getElementById('firstWindow').contentWindow.document.myFunction()`

`window.frame["firstWindow"].myFunction()`

The scritp is inside
`document.getElementById('firstWindow').contentWindow.document`. But how do I call it?

[image]

Here is how the code looks like:

```
<html>
<body>
    <--- Content from iFrame -->
    <iframe id="firstWindow" name="firstWindow" src="/test">
    <html>
    <head>

        <script>
              myFunction(){
                  console.log('test');
              };
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        some text
    </body>
    </html>
    </iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe/11796313

Comment: Already read that and that doesn't work for me. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to call the iframe function.

### Way 1

In your case, you can use `document.getElementById("firstWindow").contentWindow.myFunction()` to trigger.

### Way 2

Use `window.frames`.
`window.frames` is an array, you can set the iframe name with `window.name="this is iframe test"` in "test.html"
Then you can iterator the array, and compare the name, then trigger it.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < window.frames.length; i++) {
    if (window.frames[i].name === "this is iframe test") {
        window.frames[i].myFunction()
    }
}
```

### Way 3

Use postMessage.
In the way1 and way2, you need to assign function in the `window` object.

```
<body>
<script>
// this one
window.myFunction = function(){}
// or this one
function myFunction(){}
</script>
</body>
```

In the Way3, you can hide the myFunction then you also can trigger it.
Here is an example.

```
// a.html
<html>
<body>
        <iframe id="firstWindow" src="/b.html">
        </iframe>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("firstWindow").contentWindow.postMessage({data: "hi"});
            }, 500)
        </script>
</body>
</html>

// b.html
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        (function() {
            function myFunction() {
                console.log("test");
            }
            window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
                myFunction()
            })
        })()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then in a.html, you can try use the way1 or way2, like `document.getElementById("firstWindow").contentWindow.myFunction()`.
`myFunction` will not be called becuase the scope problem.

Comment: Both first and second method doesn't work in my case. I'm not sure why. I get the error myFunction is not function

Comment: You can't write html body tag in your <iframe></iframe>. iframe depend the "src", so you need to write code in "/test" html. In first html, you only have this `<iframe id="firstWindow" name="firstWindow" src="/test"></iframe>`. BUT, in "/test" this html, you need to write the code `<script>function myFunction(){console.log('test');};</script>`

Comment: Oh that's how it is.. My bad I'll edit the post. The body and head tags are part of the iframe file. I just copied and pasted from page-source.

Comment: Maybe you can try it in chrome console after the page are all loaded. I think you might early call iframe function which iframe is already not loaded. Or just add setTimeout(()=>{}, 1000), 1 second to try it.

Comment: Maybe you forget to add `function` keyword in front of you myFunction?