# How to get a "href" attribute in an iframe? Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, iframe

I have an external iframe. Inside that iframe i search for a specific link. I want to know the link href. The following code seems to find me the a element. But i get undefined for the attr href.

Finding the a element in the iframe which seems to work, i get an element:

```
$('.content-7232342').contents().find('body > a:first-of-type')
```

Trying to get the href attribute results in undefined:

```
$('.content-7232342').contents().find('body > a:first-of-type').attr('href')
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600488/calling-javascript-function-in-iframe

Comment: @evolutionxbox no

Comment: Is the content of the iframe hosted on a different domain to the parent window?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes it's a external website.

Comment: Unfortunately in that case what you're trying to do is not possible. Browsers are prevented from accessing/reading/updating the DOM of a cross-domain iframe for security reasons (in order to prevent spoofing, phishing etc. attacks)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But the iframe content is in my DOM, why can't i read the content in my DOM even if it's from a iframe, i don't want to add content, only read what is already in my DOM.

Comment: That's the problem - it's not in your DOM. The content of the iframe is rendered in it's own DOM which is not accessible to the outer page for the reasons I described in my previous comment. If you use devtools to inspect the page structure you will see the separate DOMs listed.